# AssertionError: Override list has odd length:it must be a list of pairs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'd need some help for the error I got.
I don't know where the problem is.

Here is my code.

```
--> 223     _assert_with_logging(
    224         len(cfg_list) % 2 == 0,
    225         "Override list has odd length: {}; it must be a list of pairs".format(
    226             cfg_list
    227         ),
    228     )
```

with error:

> AssertionError: Override list has odd length: ['/home/asoyana/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-d0ad88fd-ae82-4a40-838d-03d06b2f4465.json']; it must be a list of pairs

Comment: Could you add the code please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert` raises an `AssertionError` when its condition is **not** met. The condition was `len(cfg_list) % 2 == 0` which was not met.

It seems an internal error has occurred in file you don't access (`/home/asoyana/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-d0ad88fd-ae82-4a40-838d-03d06b2f4465.json`).

---

I suggest you try these until the solution is resolved:

- Restart your IDE / notebook
- Restart your computer
- Re-install Juptyer